# wpf upload file to server

Tags: wpf, wcf, file

I am developing a wpf app that communicates to db with wcf. One requirement is to upload files, and index them for later retrieval. What is the best method of doing this without reinventing the wheel. I am scared to use wcf for this fearing timeouts. Solution needs to be in a background thread, allow me to track progress, retry or continue on failure, and be encrypted. I can't find a file upload control like I had in silverlight / asp.net

Or should I b integrating into a dms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asp.Net WebApi for that kind of stuff. There is nothing bad in using diffirent tools. You can host it in any app, and it will be simple http upload.

Serverside code example: [Uploading large files using ASP.NET Web API and Azure Blob Storage](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Uploading-large-files-386ec0af/sourcecode?fileId=60619&pathId=765329731)

Comment: Just to show that asp.net is inside, so , generaly, your upload code going to be same. And even same, if you want to selfhost WebApi without IIS =)

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.Net.WebClient.Upload`.

Comment: seems like this is the route to go. do i still need to write an asp.net page to receive the file? tx

Answer (score 0):

MS Sql Server's [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is nice for storing files since the files are managed by SQL (where they are stored, the file name (guaranteeing uniqueness), etc) but yet behind the scenes, they are stored on the file system and not actually in the database (bloating your db).  Your code sees them as BLOBs, but they are actually files.

WCF can handle transmitting any generic [stream of large data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).  There are a few restrictions to your operation contract (WCF's name for a web method) to get that to work.  Although, this method does not have a good way to report transmission progress (that i know of).  If this doesn't work the way you would like, you can always resort to the other solutions people here are submitting or FTP.

Also check out WCF's transport security for encryption.

You will have to manage this in your own background thread.  See BackgroundWorker for a thread that works in the background, can report progress to the UI thread (very important), and when the thread completes, it offers a method that again reports back to the UI thread.

Whatever method you choose, you will have to handle timeouts, so if it's WCF, FTP, WebClient.Upload, etc you will still have to handle the same problem but in slightly different ways.  At least with WCF, the timeout timing is configured in your application config file, so you can easily tweak the timing.